# Warning from validator when serving own ads in AMP

Tags: amp-html

I'm investigating moving some pages on our website bachtrack.com to be AMP-compatible, and I need to move the advertisements. These are not sourced from an external network: they are simply images from our own server.

I am looking at the documentation for the `<amp-ad>` tag (https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/extended/amp-ad.html) and I have added in the line to serve ads from a custom domain:

```
<meta name="amp-3p-iframe-src" content="https://assets.your-domain.com/path/to/remote.html">
```

I have used the following code for the ad:

```
<amp-ad width='200' height='200' type='_ping_'></amp-ad>
```

I couldn't find any documentation on which type to use, but "*ping*" seemed the best of the few types in the list allowed in validator.js.

I now seem to be able to serve ads, but there's a nasty warning from the validator:

> The tag 'amp-ad extension .js script' is missing or incorrect, but required by 'amp-ad'. This will soon be an error.

I can't see anything in the documentation that explains what to do about this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Damn, stupid question. I missed the required script